# xcode7 ios9 about libz.tbd is not an object file (not allowed in a library)

Tags: ios9, xcode7

Error:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/lib/libz.tbd is not an object file (not allowed in a library)

If I replace `libz.dylib` with `libz.tbd`, xcode shows this bug. My project is a Cocoa Touch Static Library.

Comment: Could you describe what you want to do?

Comment: Are you sure you need this?

Comment: I need to make a static library. when I used xcode7 to recompile my project,project can not compile with libz.dylib.so I replace libz.dylib with libz.tbd.then show this bug. xcode7 has no libz.dylib.

Comment: Improved english grammar

Answer (score 13):

I found the solution here:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4572

To summarize:

1. Remove the libz.tbd file from the Libraries and Frameworks area.
2. Edit your build settings for Other Linker Flags add "-lz"

It isn't ideal because it bypasses the GUI for managing the linked libraries in your project, but it works.

Answer (score 11):

The below steps solved the issue. Reference [solution](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4572)

As per this article:

1. Delete all references to .tbd files from either your linked
   libraries phase, or from the copied bundle resources phase (where
   they sometimes will be added).
2. Go to Build Phases >Link Binary with Librairies > + > Add other -> Add a       library to your project, then click 'Add Other...' then
   press Shift+Command+G and type in the path '/usr/lib' - you'll find libz.dylib there.
3. add "-lz" to the other linker flags

Comment: You can open libz.tbd in text editor to see path to the dynamic lib it references.  On Xcode 8 adding libz.tbd to BuildPhases>Link BInaryWithLibrary worked to build an iOS app.  However tbd files seem to *NOT* be supported when building an iOS static library. Deleting libz.tbd & replacing with libz.1.dylib & add "-lz" link flag as suggested here did work - Thank you!  The tbd files can be founded under your Xcode app.  The path is
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib
Also Zlib has very liberal license http://www.zlib.net/