# Where I can get libxml2.2.dylib?

Tags: html, ios, parsing, libxml2

I need to parse a html string on iOS, I came across to Raywenderlich tutorial by using libxml2 and hpple. I already go to the website http://www.xmlsoft.org, but I can't find the download link or maybe something that direct to it. I'm quite experienced on Obj-C, but I', fairly new to C. How to get the dylib? maybe by compiling my self? could you give me the step how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple made it easy.

Follow the steps from 1 to 8 in screenshots,

[image]

[image]

and you're done!
[image]

Note, Most of the frameworks you can add by following the above steps.

Comment: Thanks.. It made me realize that the libs is already available by xcode, but I can't add the libs by adding like that on XCode 7. the additional solution is on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32734097/xcode7-ios9-about-libz-tbd-is-not-an-object-file-not-allowed-in-a-library

Answer (score 0):

As you included the iOS tag, I suspect you are developing an iOS app and going to ignore your remark regarding C.

You can simply include it; it's in the list of available frameworks and libraries to link to.