# Add libsqlite3.0 into a pod project error

Tags: ios, sqlite, cocoapods

I'm creating a pod that needs a static library (AdobeMobileLibrary.a)

[image]
This library has a dependency with libsqlite3.0, but adding it and then compiling it shows this error

error:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
>   file:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.tbd
>   is not an object file (not allowed in a library)

Someone who can help me? Thanks

Comment: Check here if it's your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32734097/xcode7-ios9-about-libz-tbd-is-not-an-object-file-not-allowed-in-a-library

Comment: @YunCHEN I tried it but it did not work